# Getting SEO errors with BreadcrumbList

Tags: html, aem

Getting below errors when I run my code snippet in [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

[image]

1. The value provided for item.id must be a valid URL.
2. position: A value for the position field is required.

**code snippet:**

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb clearfix hide-mobile"
  data-sly-list="${controller.breadcrumbModel.items}"
  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"
    data-sly-test="${!itemList.last}">
    <a itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item"
       href="${item.url}" title="${item.title}">
      <span itemprop="name">${item.title}</span>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="${itemList.index}" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" data-sly-test="${itemList.last}">
    <span itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item">
      <span itemprop="name">${item.title}</span>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="${itemList.index}" />
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue: "*position: A value for the position field is required.*"**

You have to add the `position` property to specify the position of the `ListItem`.

```
<meta itemprop="position" content="1"/>
```

**Issue: "*The value provided for item.id must be a valid URL.*"**

You have to remove the `itemscope` on the `<a>` element.

**So the valid markup looks like the following:**

```
<ol class="breadcrumb clearfix show-mobile" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="/content/xyz-at/de/abcd.html" title="Content page">
      <span itemprop="name">Content page</span>

      <!-- set the hierarchical value dynamically to the following element. -->
      <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

**The whole markup of the `BreadcrumbList`**

The complete valid markup of the [`BreadcrumbList`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) looks like the following:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb clearfix hide-mobile" data-sly-list="${controller.breadcrumbModel.items}" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" data-sly-test="${!itemList.last}">
    <a itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="${item.url}" title="${item.title}">
      <span itemprop="name">${item.title}</span>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="${itemList.index}" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" data-sly-test="${itemList.last}">
    <span itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing">
      <span itemprop="name">${item.title}</span>
      <link itemprop="item" href="${item.url}" />
      <meta itemprop="position" content="${itemList.index}" />
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The last level of the [`BreadcrumbList`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) is not clickable, but it is visible. The markup is valid on the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

---

**Additional resources for Breadcrumbs in Structured Data:**

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb
- https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

Comment: the changes which you mentioned resolved both the issues. But  say if I have two or more lists , content="1" should not be hardcoded right..I guess it should take the hierarchical value of the breadcrumb. Please provide me more insight of the same.

Comment: Also below is one more code snippet which is slightly different from the above one and facing the same item.id error with first span element -                                                                                                      <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
     <span itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item">
      <span itemprop="name">Knorr</span>
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1"/>
     </span>
    </li>

Comment: @RashmiKs - yes you have to set the hierarchical value of the breadcrumb dynamically (starting with 1 to nth level in the breadcrumb). Your second code snippet is valid (no item.id error). I also recommend to use JSON-LD to set structured data on your site (if possible).

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my second code snippet. Please check. If I replace 'span' tag with 'a' tag it doesn't give errors. But don't know why it gives error with 'span' tag.

Comment: I got three errors on other elements. It is difficult to remove all the issues without the whole original code. ... but I recommend to use JSON-LD to add structured data to your site. It is much more easier to handle and don't get broken by changing the markup.

Comment: I am not allowed to use JSON-LD .. the whole block of code(updated code snippet) is shown above. But that works if I use not only 'a' tag but add href link with it instead of first span element in the  data-sly-test = "${itemList.last} block

Comment: Since the end element of a breadcrumb( abc > def > xyz) where xyz should not be a hyperlink , how can I resolve the issue without using anchor tag and href, kindly suggest.

Comment: This is the Excellent Solution I got.